# How to scan open windows

Tags: java, window

Is it possible to scan thru all open windows with java and find one that is specified. Say notepad? For example I want notepad to be front and center open and ready, its open and when I run my program it would scan all open windows and bring notepad forward.

Comment: *"when I run my program it would scan all open windows and bring notepad forward."* One way is to use `Desktop.open(File)` where the file in this case is one associated with Notepad.  E.G. a `app-help.txt`.  This is a strange requirement though.  Why do you want any other window brought to front when your app. starts, what relevance does *any* other app. have to yours?

Comment: ah well my program is kinda sorta we crawling and i want it to post links it visits in historical order on a notepad so i can see the history sorta thing. not a big requirement but one i would like to have.

Comment: *"see the history"*  Forget Notepad.  Use a `JList` for the history entries, and a `JEditorPane` or other components for the details on each entry.

Answer (score 0):

I have extensive experience on Windows system. And I know that Windows system specific requirements are properly met in Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI). I have used WMI successfully like what you’re doing but I never did it with Java. Here’s a link at 
[WMI explanations](http://www.vijaykandy.com/2009/09/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-from-java/). Please tell me which ones you tried and state your conclusion.

Believe me, once you know how to access WMI with Java, you can do almost anything on a Windows system. Of course, if I am tasked with such a requirement, I would use C# and .NET. But Java is your choice 

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JNA.

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;


// https://github.com/twall/jna#readme
//    you need 2 jars : jna-3.5.1.jar and platform-3.5.1.jar

public class ActivateNotepad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("Notepad", null);
            if (hwnd == null) {
                System.out.println("No Notepad instance detected");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Notepad instance found.");
                User32.INSTANCE.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);  
            }
        }
}
```